# What is the meaning of this phrase: "Vous m'en direz des nouvelles"

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques

I'd like to know its precise meaning. Does it mean "Tell me what you think about it (the next time we meet)"? I don't know how to use this phrase.

> - Ce collier, je l’ai fait moi-même. **Vous m'en direz des nouvelles** !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression means : "Tell me about it !". You use it when you want your interlocutor to know how much you find something great.

"Goûte ce vin, tu m'en diras des nouvelles !!!"
means
"taste this vine, believe me, you will find it wonderful !!"

Answer (score 1):

This expression often implies that I believe that you'll like it very much - whatever is being referred to (and thus we'll talk about it again). See for example the [Wiktionary in French](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vous_m%E2%80%99en_direz_des_nouvelles).

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it means that! The problem with expressions, is that they are very hard to translate in English because of the complexity of French!